# Must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Asp.Net MVC 4 code and it raise the error on line 18 of controller `DealController`. Right now it only happen after I rebuild the project when I'm debugging using VS 2012 on my local PC.

```
Line 16: private IQueryable<Deal> Deals
Line 17: {
Line 18:    get { return User.IsInRole("Admin") ? _db.Deals : _db.Deals.Where(d => d.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name); }
Line 19: }
```

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

Should I add attribute `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` on all the controllers which calls `User.IsInRole()` or `User.Identity.Name`? Right now it's only added on `AccountController`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128218/you-must-call-the-websecurity-initializedatabaseconnection-method-before-you-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` for the controller solved the issue.

Comment: This is not a proper solution. Because if you have the following code:


    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
      // ...
    }


As an action filter, ISMA hooks into OnActionExecuting to perform the lazy initialization work, but this can be too late in the life cycle.
Then it is going to crash. For example if you have the following code:

    [Authorize(Roles="Sales")]